# multi variable calculus, confused about changing limits of integration

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

[image]

I am really confused and would appreciate help on this....

I know if you have constants as limits of integration and you want to switch them
you just switch the limits from dx to dy and switch the order of integration of variables.....

however i am really confused about whats going on below....how can you have functions as limits of integration
and in this case what do you do to solve it because the below example doesnt make sense to me....

how are they finding new limit of integration because this seems if you have functions as limits you cant just switch
them you have to do some weird stuff to get new limits, what do you do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first integration on the RHS is holding $y$ constant. Therefore it is not a function in the limit, it is a "constant". Afterwards it is then an integration $wrt$ to $y$.

Comment: i understand that but do you notice they changed limits ofi ntegration 0 to 4 is now 0 to 2 :S this is what i am asking.....how do you change limits of integration what do you need to do differently when limits of integration are functions rather than constants

Answer (score 1):

I figured out why the limit changes....the region you are bounded by changes when you switch the limit of integration when the limit is a function so you must enter your new limits of integration based on the function thats in the limits of integration bounding your integration area.

Comment: Absolutely, yes. Well done!